# GMMap zooming with mouse wheel.

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser, delphi-10.1-berlin, gmlib

I would like to know how zooming the map with mouse wheel on a GMMap into a TWebBrowser D10.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You needs to add ScrollWheel to the GMMap.NonVisualProp.Options set

```
GMMap.NonVisualProp.Options := GMMap.NonVisualProp.Options + [ScrollWheel];
```

or exclude it

```
GMMap.NonVisualProp.Options := GMMap.NonVisualProp.Options - [ScrollWheel];
```

By default, this set includes this option

Comment: The ScrollWheel option in GMMap is set True, but nothing happens using mouse wheel.
Any idea why?
Thanks

Comment: That work fine into megademo. What version of IE have you installed in your system?

Comment: I have IE11 installed (W7)

Comment: try with a new application, with only a TWebBrowser and a TGMMap. If this don't work, try [this](http://www.cadetill.com/cosas-del-twebbrowser/) (spanish only, sorry)

Comment: Thank you,
Tried as you said, This works, but not in my app.
I've set both TWebBrowser and GMMap properties the same way in the app and in the test.
Any idea of what causes this difference?

Comment: This property, do you set it at design time or run time? If run time, after set, you need to reload the map with calling DoMap method

Comment: All properties for both Components are set at Design time.

Comment: Add .\src path to the Library path and set a breakpoint at method DoMap (file GMMap.pas line 2928) and check property value.

Comment: Thx, 
did that but ScrollWheel is set True into GMMap.pas.

Comment: can you send me a demo program (sources) to reproduce this issue?

Comment: This app requires a flight simulator and a wheather generator installed to work.
How can I do?

Comment: send me a email and we talk in private

Comment: e-mail sent through your blog.

Comment: @PierreChassang, your problem was resolved?... i have problem same

Comment: Email not received. Try with my nick to gmail.com